# Regex to get text between " symbols

Tags: java, regex

i got this string:

```
"streamUrl":"http://media.mysite.com/stream/WF9bRDueA0sm?stream_token=f2EmQ",
```

Ok, now i have a function in java

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                        "<row><column>(.*)</column></row>",
                        Pattern.DOTALL
                    );

                Matcher matcher = p.matcher(code); //That is the code up, "streamUrl...

                if(matcher.matches()){
                        testo2.setText(matcher.group(1));

            }
```

Ok now i have to change the Regex Pattern to get text between

```
"streamUrl":"
```

and

```
",
```

That's are special char and i don't know how to add it to the pattern, i tryied

```
Pattern.compile(
                    "Pattern.compile(
                    ""streamUrl":"(.*)",",
                    Pattern.DOTALL
                );(.*)</column></row>",
                    Pattern.DOTALL
                );
```

But it's not working, can someone help me?
i need to get this: http://media.mysite.com/stream/WF9bRDueA0sm?stream_token=f2EmQ
Thanks in advice, matteo :)

Comment: no. what you have is a part of a json string. consider the whole thing a a json object, properly parse it and access elements. matching and substringing is soooo low-level

Comment: search the web for a json lib ...

Comment: For the record, finding any kind of matching symbols isn't a regular language, and thus can't be matched with a standard regular expression (though there are some pretty nasty-looking ways to make a regex non-regular). 3rd-party libraries like in the answers is definitely your best bet.

Comment: You can split your string on `:` as a delimiter and than combine the last two elements of the resultant array but I would suggest going through proper channel to extract the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you match it is:

```
String regex = "\"streamUrl\":\"(.*)\",";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

But as stated in the comments you are way better using JSON.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using JSONTokener

```
try  {
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(yourString);
    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) tokener.nextValue();
    String output = jsonObj.getString("streamUrl");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.v("Logtag", "Problem in decoding json");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is a cleaner solution than parsing the string with a regex, imho.

Comment: Hi, i'm trying this solution... but i got an error compiling, i'm not good with the try/catch and java, it tell: Unhandled exception type JSONException

Comment: added try catch blocks. try now.

Comment: thank you very much, but now i got this error with the code: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean, i tryied to delete if (Log.DEBUG) but when i click and i have to use this function my app crash... what can i do?

Comment: can you print the complete error? Why don't you try by completely removing the Log.v line.

Comment: here's the error that make my app crash...: http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/3961/11c1e71d654a46329ff4e90.png

Comment: does your string have curly brackets, i.e. { and }, at the beginning and end of string?

Comment: in the string i have the html page source... ah, yes i have some braqckets in the string... does this cause the crash?

Comment: that is the problem... i assumed it's a proper json object (read about json here - http://www.json.org/)... in your case you should try Gilberto's solution. Who is sending this output to your app?

Comment: I am only trying to catch the stream url of the song and playing it with one music player, thank you very much Mukesh :)

Comment: This definitely should be considered. String parsing is fairly easy, but can quickly become a mess